# Strange behaviour using legacy packages with ESM modules

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

I am trying to use the `calculate-size` package in my app that uses ES modules. This package is very old and declares it's exports using the following code:

```js
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.default = function() { /* ... */ }
```

However when I try to import the package as follows I experience some strange behaviour:

```js
// index.mjs
import fn from "calculate-size";
console.log(fn)
```

I expect the output of this to be that `fn` is a function however it is an object containing a property named `default`. It would be possible for me to use `fn.default` however this would conflict with the package's typings.

I would like to understand some more information about this behaviour as I haven't been able to find any documentation about this issue. I also want to understand if there is a fix on my end of if the only solution is to contact the package maintainer.